# Creating an OpenID identity server using AspNetSqlMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

There are plenty of tutorials out there about how to be an OpenID relying party - but how can i configure my ASP.net MVC server to be an OpenID Identity server that uses AspNetSqlMembershipProvider (and the corresponding forms authentication form)?

I might add that i could use another MembershipProvider, but i cannot be a relying party, i must be the identity server.